# If statement skips to else

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm pretty new to Java coming from Python so please pardon my retardedness. I'm trying to make a simple if statement and it won't work :(. It ignores the if statement and goes straight else.

I've tried to use .contains and .equalsIgnoreCase in the if statement.

```py
package me.johnminton;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String species_animal;
        System.out.println("Please enter your species: ");
        species_animal = user_input.next();

        if (species_animal.contains("Erectus")) {
            System.out.println("random input statement");


        }
        else
            {
            System.out.println("okay");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping for it output "random input statement" if I input Erectus in the first input. But instead, it goes straight to the else and outputs "okay".

Comment: The if statement looks OK, try printing your variable ```species_animal``` to see what it is assigned to. Btw your code works for me.

Comment: This looks to be a problem with your scanner, actually.  Try using `input.nextLine()` instead.

Comment: The code, at least the portion you're showing us..... works. What is the code that you're **not** showing us?

Comment: Instead of contains try using equals or equalsignorecase string method if you want an exact match with Erectus.

Answer (score 3):

The `next()` method just fetches a single word from the scanner, although you can change that behaviour by specifying a delimiter for the scanner.

In your case, if you type `Eructussian` or something similar, you'll get the result you want, but if you type `Home Erectus`, you won't.

I suspect you meant to use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`, which fetches an entire line of text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your scanner isn’t finishing without getting a return key.  Try ‘user_input.nextLine()’ instead of ‘user_input.next()’